# VS C++: A task was canceled

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I tried to compile this in Visual Studio Premium 2013 (last version), I am using Windows 10. (I hope not my OS is the problem, on CodeBlocks is working really fine).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

And I get this error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: OtherTest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>A task was canceled.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any source code that I try to compile, finish with this error (even a empty one).

Comment: A small note: the version of Visual Studio in your question (2013) doesn't match the tag *visual-studio-2012*.

Comment: My mistake, i will correct it